# Inside Docker container - crond running but no cronjobs executed

Tags: cron, docker

I have built a container from a Dockerfile, based on an Archlinux base image. Using a "RUN" command I have installed "cronie", since Arch does not come with any form of cron. Now, after the container is built, I run it and attach to it. I start manually the cron daemon, verify that it is indeed running with "ps -aux" and make the required cronjobs with "crontab -e". The thing is, no cronjobs are run...

Any ideas?

Comment: check cron.log file and paste error here?

Comment: Will try to do later today.

Comment: @AbhishekAnandAmralkar There is no "cron.log" file in Arch Linux. I tried "journalctl -u cronie" but it returns "No journal files were found". Still, the daemon is running, and the jobs configures inside crontab.

Comment: check for systemd/Timers ..Timers are systemd unit files with a suffix of .timer   systemctl list-timers will list all the timers if any..

Comment: I mention that this is taking place inside a Docker container. No systemd is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the package fcron, and run the cron process in foreground mode:

```
fcron -f
```

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot Cron it may be handy to run *syslog* in Docker container.
As [described here](http://raid6.com.au/posts/docker-cron-rsyslog/) Cron may refuse to interpret its hard-linked configuration files which is a typical situation on Docker's layered *overlay(fs)* file system. If Cron logs something like `NUMBER OF HARD LINKS > 1 (/etc/crontab)` to *syslog* it may help to use the following command in container's entry script:

```
touch /etc/crontab /etc/cron.*/*
```